# call json (with jquery) in google spreadsheet function

Tags: jquery, json, google-apps-script

I would like to write an own function for google spreadsheets that calls a json service.
I know how to call json this with jquery, but how do I do this in a spreadsheets function?

```
$.getJSON(service_url + '?callback=?', params, function(response) {
    $.each(response.itemListElement, function(i, element) {
      console.log({text:element['result']});

    });
  });
```

Comment: Are you trying this in Apps Script,  in the javascript of a web app hosted with apps script, or in another site that's supposed to make GET or POST requests to your apps script hosted web app?

Comment: I'm trying it in Apps Script in the Script Editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use JQuery within Apps Script itself, there is no support for using 3rd party libraries in the same fashion as you would typically with JavaScript on a website.

Especially JQuery which is meant for DOM manipulation, of which Apps Script does not have. There is no window in apps Script, there are no elements, you're script is remotely executed on a Google server.

As for calling a service, look into the [URLFetchApp Utility](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app). This allows you to make a variety of GET, POST, PUT..etc calls to other web services.

Here is a sample script:

```
function myFunction(){
  var url = "myUrl";
  var options = {
    method: 'get',
    user: 'someUser'

  }

  var results = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
}
```

**Note**: You can manually port some libraries that don't rely on a window and similar objects, similar to how a developer ported UnerscoreJS into Apps Script.